# MySQL Database Design. How to use dates in a relational database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm in the process of building a database compiling various news articles from various sources and I'm trying to work out the most efficient way to catalogue the dates the articles were written.

As it stands I'm thinking of having one table with all the dates on, then pointing the article entries in the DB to the appropriate entry in the date table.

Obviously several problems with that spring to mind, not least of which being the incredibly unwieldy and excessively long list of dates I would have to create.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Bearing in mind that several tables within my database will be using the dates table.

Thanks in advance, and thank you for reading my essay...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ethan has suggested simply store the date in the same table as the article, no need for a lookup.

You may wish to store some details of an article separate from the body of the text, to  potentially speed up searches but I would start simple. Store all relevant data in one table and only resort to partitioning *if* things are running slowly (avoid premature optimisation).

In addition to your main tables I would advise you to create an auxiliary [Calendar Table](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporal-data-techniques-in-sql-/) to assist in date based queries. Contrary to what you said:

> ...the incredibly unwieldy and excessively long list of dates I would have to create.

A table containing dates for the next 50 years is only just over 18k rows, not much at all.

If you are going to be working with dates a lot I'd recommend you take a look at [Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/rts/publications.html) by Richard Snodgrass, it's an excellent resource.

Comment: Calendar tables allow you to store certain attributes that are associated with a date.  Examples are fiscal info and holiday info.  It would also allow you to find dates for which there were no articles, should the need arise.

Comment: @DanBracuk there are better ways to perform those types of functions without moving the dates into a separate table

Comment: @Tony A table containing only days of the year is 18k rows. A table containing every second for 50 years is 1.5 Billion which could run into performance issues `(8 byte DateTime + 4 Byte Primary Key) * 50 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 = ~19Gb`.

Comment: @Ethan - Yes, a table with all possible _times_ would be silly, but my interpretation of the question is that an article has an associated publication **date**, there is no mention of a time component.

Comment: @Ethan - I've edited my answer to emphasise it is in _additon_ to the tables holding the articles and is only to assist in date based queries. In case you were thinking I was advocating the use of a separate table for the dates. DanBracuk was not suggesting a separate table either, he was pointing out the advantages to having a `Calendar` table storing additional information about each day, not to move the dates to a separate table. Have a look at the link I posted about `Calendar` tables if you've not used them before.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [MySQL DateTime format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html). Don't create a separate table for dates. MySQL is optimized for storing that format in each record and performing operations on it.

Creating a separate table for dates is more used for [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) than [OLTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLTP), and I assume you are building an OLTP system.

The biggest problem with creating a separate table is that you would need to have a record for every possible time that might be used, and then you need to perform a lookup on that table to find the foreign key. That just is not a good idea at all.

Seeing as you are asking this question, I don't believe that you would need to get any more optimized than simply storing the datetime in each row. If you were building something where it would matter, you would probably know better than I would anyways.